# Clippy complaining on strict f32 comparison

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

I have a test assertion that looks like this

```
assert_eq!(-0.000031989493, res);
```

which works for the test. But when I run Clippy on my test it complains.

```
error: strict comparison of `f32` or `f64`
   --> src/main.rs:351:9
    |
351 |         assert_eq!(-0.000031989493, res);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: `f32::EPSILON` and `f64::EPSILON` are available for the `error_margin`
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#float_cmp
    = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I've looked at the provided link https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#float_cmp and rewrote it like this instead.

```
assert_eq!(
    true,
    (res - -0.000031989493).abs() < f32::EPSILON
);
```

But that makes the test less readable and if the test fails I can't see the result of what I'm testing in the output.

How should I write my f32 comparison assertions so that Clippy is happy and so that the tests still output the values in the terminal if it fails?

Or should I just not run Clippy on my tests?

Thanks!

Comment: Make your own macro or function, say `assert_almost_eq!` or look for already made by somebody

Comment: Nobody can answer this for you because the definition of what's "close enough" to compare equal varies according to what, specifically, you're doing. Sometimes "equal" means within a certain range; sometimes it means within a certain percentage of a target value; sometimes it means just this exact value, nothing different. Epsilons are there to help with *some* of those cases but there is no one way to compare using epsilon either. You must decide whether Clippy's suggestion is right or not based on what your program is doing.

Comment: (Note that you can allow certain things in Clippy on a lint-by-lint basis; you don't have to go all the way to "don't run clippy at all")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've copied and altered the assert_eq macro a bit

```
macro_rules! assert_almost_eq {
    ($left:expr, $right:expr, $prec:expr) => {{
        match (&$left, &$right) {
            (left_val, right_val) => {
                let diff = (left_val - right_val).abs();

                if diff > $prec {
                    panic!(
                        "assertion failed: `(left == right)`\n      left: `{:?}`,\n     right: `{:?}`",
                        &*left_val, &*right_val
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }};
}
```

I don't really understand everything, like the reason for the match, but it seems to solve my problem.

Comment: You don't need to rewrite macro, you can add custom panic message like this :  
`assert!((actual - expected).abs() < f32::EPSILON, "left: {:?} not equal right: {:?}", actual, expected)`

Comment: Thanks, that's really good to know. But in this case it would bloat my tests a bit since I compare a bunch of values in every test.